# How to generate composite html report for distributed load testing in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Context: I am running JMeter load test on a distributed load system with 1:2 master slave ratio, with the following command:

jmeter -n -t "home/jmeterscripts/EventGridScript.jmx" -R slave1:1099,slave2:1099 -l "home/jmeterscripts/Result.csv" -e -o "home/jmeterscripts/HTMLReports"

Will the result report to the same report.html because I am getting error of Result.csv presence from slave2 while reporting? how to handle it this, didn't find similar post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this message because `home/jmeterscripts/Result.csv` **is present already**, if you don't need the results file from the previous run add [`-f` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) to your command line:

```
jmeter -n -t -"home/jmeterscripts/EventGridScript.jmx" -R slave1:1099,slave2:1099 -f -l "home/jmeterscripts/Result.csv" -e -o "home/jmeterscripts/HTMLReports"
```

> `-f`, `--forceDeleteResultFile`
> force delete existing results files and web report folder if present before starting the test

The results are not being stored on slaves, the slaves send test metrics to the master so the master collects the statistics from all the slaves so no matter how many slaves you have you always get a single [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) and a single HTML Reporting Dashboard.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)